# find a specific string and delete the whole structure

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have a vertical file where each word (token) is on the separate line in 4 columns. There are also metastructures `<doc>`, `<s>`, ...
The documents looks as follows:

```
<doc name="sth" url="http">
<p>
<s>
Here   here   k1gInSc1   here
is   be   k1gMnPc2   be
a  a   k2eAgMnPc1d1   a
sentence   sentence   k1gMnPc1   sentence
<g/>
.       .       kIx.
</s>
</p>
</doc>
```

the problem is that sometimes there is wrong encoding with characters as **Ă** or **Ä** in the first column, e.g.

```
<doc name="sth" url="http">
<p>
<s>
Here   here   k1gInSc1   here
is   be   k1gMnPc2   be
Ă  Ă   k?   Ă
sentence   sentence   k1gMnPc1   sentence
<g/>
.       .       kIx.
</s>
</p>
</doc>
```

I would need to find these characters and delete the whole document structure. So, if I find **Ă** on a line, I need to delete the whole content between `<doc...>` all lines `</doc>`.

My file has a billion lines and ca a few thousand lines contain wrong encoded characters.

I used grep to finding bad characters:

```
xzcat file.vert.xz | grep -i "Ă\|Ĺ\|ľ\|ş\|Ä" > file_bad_characters.txt
```

How can I detect these characters and delete not only the line but the whole text between `<doc>`structures.

Comment: Thank for your tips. Finally, I managed to solve the problem with the bad encoding, so I did not have to delete them.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is to use a proper XML parser. However, in this case, the following might work as a workaround:

1. Remove all blank lines from the file:

   ```
   sed -i '/^\s*$/d' file
   ```
2. Add a blank line before each `<doc>`:

   ```
   sed -i 's/<doc/\n\n<doc/' file
   ```
3. User Perl's "paragraph mode" where "lines" are defined as "paragraphs" (sections of text preceded by an empty line):

   ```
   perl -00 -ne 'print unless /[ĂĹľşÄ]/' file > newfile
   ```

   Or, to make the replacements in the original file:

   ```
   perl -i.bak -00 -ne 'print unless /[ĂĹľşÄ]/' file
   ```

**IMPORTANT**: This assumes a well-structured file where everything is inside `<doc...` tags.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something you can do with just grep, I'm afraid; this requires that you retain some context about lines which grep can't provide. However, there are several other languages that can do this; here's an example with `awk`:

```
awk '/<doc>/ {text=""; output=1}
     /Ă|Ĺ|ľ|ş|Ä/{output=0}
     {text = text $0 "\n"}
     /<\/doc>/ {if(output==1){printf "%s", text}}"
```

This creates a buffer called `text` when we see a token `<doc>` in the input, and sets a flag to signal that we want to see the text printed; this flag is cleared when the forbidden characters are encountered. When we encounter the token `</doc>`, we check if the flag is still set; if so, we display the buffer. Finally, every line is added to our buffer, regardless of whether the flag is set or not.

Comment: This works and I used it many times. Thanks!